# How do I use CSS to make an element level with a portion of a picture if I don't know exactly where that portion of the picture is?

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to make a div level with the bottom of a portion of a picture where the full picture extends past where I need it to be.
[Example of what I am talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtBsW.png) I have tried absolute positioning, but I am afraid of responsiveness once I do the mobile and widescreen versions. It also didn't work when I tried it. I tried changing the heights of the divs, but I am not sure if it is truly level. This is my first project, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="type-and-hand-lettering">
    <div class="type-and-hand-lettering-container">
      <div class="three">03</div>
      <div class="three-content">
        <h3>type and hand-lettering</h3>
        <p>
          I can help you make your type flow nice and look flawless.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <img
      src="/assets/type-and-hand-lettering.png"
      alt="type and hand lettering"
    />
  </div>
```

Here is the SCSS:

```
.type-and-hand-lettering {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1.5fr;
// grid-gap: 1rem;
align-items: center;
margin-top: 100px;
margin-right: 5rem;
margin-left: 5rem;
margin-bottom: 150px;

&-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;

  .three {
    color: $primary-color;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: $lust;
    width: 100%;

    &-content {
      width: 100%;
      h3 {
        color: #02281b;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-family: $lust;
      }

      p {
        color: #02281b;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: $roboto;
      }
    }
  }
}
}

img {
 width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid absolute positioning , you can use the

```
transform: translateY(-amountOfRemsYouWannaMoveTheElementUp);
```